# How do I make the bot react to itself with 2 different reactions

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to allow the bot to react to itself with both thumbs up and down. here is my code:

```
const args = message.content.split(' ');
if (message.content.includes('<poll')) {
  message.delete()
  let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle(`Poll In ${message.guild.name}`)
  .setDescription(args.slice(1).join(' '))
  .setFooter(`Started by ${message.author.username}`)
  .setColor('#ffc0cb')

  message.channel.send(embed)
  .then(sentMessage => sentMessage.react(''))
  .catch(console.error)
}
```

I tried using `.then` twice but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
message.channel.send(embed)
   .then(sentMessage => {
      sentMessage.react('')
      sentMessage.react('')
});
```

If you want your bot to react in order you have two options:

#### Option 1:

Use `async / await`:

```js
message.channel.send(embed)
   .then(sentMessage => {
      // Don't forget to make your function async, otherwise it won't work
      await sentMessage.react('')
      await sentMessage.react('')
});
```

#### Option 2:

Chain `.then()`'s:

```js
message.channel.send(embed)
   .then(sentMessage => sentMessage.react(''))
   .then(sentMessage => sentMessage.react(''))
});
```

---

#### References:

- [Official guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#reacting-in-order)

Comment: Glad I could help :)